# Angularjs : How to retrieve data from ng-options in angularjs using single string or only one loop

Tags: angularjs

good day, i would like to ask question about retrieving selected data from ng options using string as comparator.

in my controller i have this data

```
 $scope.myList = [
    { id: 0, name: "foo" },
    { id: 1, name: "foo1" },
    { id: 2, name: "foo2" }
 ];
```

for my index.html

```
 <select 
 ng-options="list.name for listin myList"
 ng-model="selectedList"
 /select>
```

so the scenario is this, i have my own way of retrieving data but it includes nested looping and my question is, is there any way's to do this just using one loop or a one liner code? because basically i already have the value from database, is there any way so that i don't need to iterate the whole list just to show the data in HTML select input or if not possible at least i wont use nested loops, thanks

this is what i tried so far

```
 // assume the value retrieved from database is "foo1"

var retrievedData = "foo1";

for(var i=0; i<myList.length; i++) {
    if(myList[i]['name'] == retrievedData ) {
        $scope.selected = myList[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one line like bellow

```
var retrievedData = "foo1";

$scope.selected =  myList.find((ele) => ele['name'] == retrievedData);
```

**find()** will return the first match.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line like bellow

myList.filter(function(listitem,listitemid){return listitem.name==retrievedData});